# Call Controllers function from Directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

How to call controllers method in directive in below code:

```
app.controller("main",['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
$scope.SelectCollege = function (){
     //Code to search college
}
}]);
```

Directive

```
    angular.module('angucomplete', [] )
        .directive('angucomplete', function ($parse, $http, $sce, $timeout) {

   link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
                $("#search_value").autocomplete({
                        source: $scope.localData,
                        select: function( event, ui ) {

                            //How to call controller's method here

                        }
                    });
            }
 });
```

Comment: Since you are not creating isolated scope, the method would be accessible in the directive if the directive is defined inside the controller html. You can do $scope.SelectCollege.

Comment: @Chandermani, Thanks.. can you elaborate your answer..

Comment: so your module and directive has same attribute `angucomplete` and also i don't see `restrict:''` in your directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include you controller with directive property

The controller option takes a string or a function. When set to a string, the name of the string is
used to look up a controller constructor function registered elsewhere in our application:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
   .directive('myDirective', function() {
   restrict: 'A', // always required
   controller: 'SomeController',
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, SomeController) {
         SomeController.doSomething(scope);
  },
})
   // elsewhere in our application
   // either in the same file or another
   // one included by our index.html
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('SomeController', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
      // controller logic goes here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the directive is placed inside the controller scope (element with ng-controller )

```
select: function( event, ui ) {

   //How to call controller's method here
   //Answer: as shown below
   $scope.SelectCollege();

}
```

Comment: how to declare directive within scope of controller

Comment: I had to add another answer because I cannot format the code in comment section. Please accept the relevant answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your controller's method to the directive's scope like so:

```
<autocomplete on-select="SelectCollege()"></autocomplete>
```

And in your directive define your scope

```
scope: {
    onSelect: "&onSelect"
}
```

Then within your directive you would just call it as:

```
 $scope.onSelect()
```

Alternatively you can just use `$scope.SelectCollege()` inside your directive if your directive is placed within controllers scope **and** your directive does not declare its own scope but inherits from controllers scope. Example:

```
<div ng-controller="main">
    <autocomplete></autocomplete>
</div>
```

Comment: Why create isolated scope when not required ?

Comment: Merely for demonstrational purposes that it can be done if needed.